# Python variable exists undefined?

Tags: python, variables, discord, undefined, exists

I am having trouble creating a simple on/off switch.
I am beginner and am writing a discord bot for fun and to learn. My bot is on more than one server and that is why a global variable isn't an option (running it on one server also changes it for others).
Putting a variable inside the command isn't an option because every time I run the command, it defines it.
I need something that exists but can only be defined by subprocesses.

```
@bot.command()
async def xxx(ctx):

    # global x # doesn't work correctly
    # x = "" # doesn't work correctly

    if x != True:
        x = True
        await ctx.send("X is on!")
 
    else:
        x = False
        await ctx.send("X is off!")


    while x == True:
        #some code calculations here, blablabla

    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

What is a solution to my problem?
Thank you.

Comment: you use the same name for function `def x()` and for variable `x = ...` - and this can makes big problems.

Comment: sorry, this is an example I don't actually use the same name, editing now, changed to def xxx()

Comment: maybe you should use dictionary with servers names  `if x["server name"] is not True:`

Comment: definitely something worth looking into, but on first glance - if I make the bot public I cannot follow all the servers to put into dictionaries, code

Comment: you don't have to add all servers at start - you can check what server runs this function and then add it to dictionary if not exists in dictionary. `if 'server name' not in x: x["server name"] = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `server` means `ctx.guild` - so you can use dictionary to keep values for different servers - `x[ctx.guild.name]` or `x[ctx.guild]`.

You don't have to create all servers at start but you can check in function if server is in dictionary and add default value.

```
# global dictionary
x = dict()

@bot.command()
async def xxx(ctx):
    # dictionary doesn't need `global x` in function

    server_name = ctx.guild.name
    
    # set default value if used first time on server/guild
    if server_name not in x:
        x[server_name] = False
        
    if not x[server_name]:
        x[server_name] = True
        await ctx.send("X is on!")
    else:
        x[server_name] = False
        await ctx.send("X is off!")

    while x[server_name]:
        #some code calculations here, blablabla

    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

---

You can also switch `True/False` using `not`

```
x[server_name] = not x[server_name]

if x[server_name]:
    await ctx.send("X is on!")
else:
    await ctx.send("X is off!")
```

Comment: Thank you! I am making progress now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the switch in a starting position. How you do that is up to you. I would personally create a switch class. The simple solution for you is to set the starting position globally outside the function. Example:

```
global x
x = 0
@bot.command()
async def x(ctx):

    if x != True:
        x = True
        await ctx.send("X is on!")
 
    else:
        x = False
        await ctx.send("X is off!")

    while x == True:
        #some code calculations here, blablabla

    await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Comment: all variables created outside functions are global and you don't have to use `global x` outside functions. You have to use `global x` inside function to change value of this global variable. without `globla x` it will still create local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping this code in an object and declaring X as a class variable IE

```
class ChatBot(object):
    x = False

    @classmethod
    @bot.command()
    def xxx(ctx):
        if x != True:
            x = True
            await ctx.send("X is on!")

        else:
            x = False
            await ctx.send("X is off!")


        while x == True:
            #some code calculations here, blablabla

        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Object Oriented Programming makes tons of things easier to implement and debug in python with the added benefit of not worrying about globals (singletons are usually best avoided unless you absolutely need them - IE logging or configs). Good Luck - also naming variables and functions is important in the long run so I suggest you make it a habit early!